# What is an alternative word for "downvote"

Tags: slang

I am curious about what another way to describe the negative action of "downvoting" could be. Is there another word out there that could be used as a replacement?

Answer (score 2):

In the context of electronic media there is "dislike" of course.

Answer (score 2):

The first word that comes to mind is the verb **fault**, which is to find reason to criticize someone or something.

Obvious related verbs and phrases then come easily, including **challenge**, **criticize**, **dispute**, **gainsay**, **disagree**, **question**, **call into question**, **discredit**, **disparage**, **belittle**, **denigrate**, and the list goes on...

Some less formal or slang verbs and phrases include **diss** / **dis** (meaning to disrespect), **flame**, and **trash talk**.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to express your disagreement on a proposal:

- To **disagree**
- To **dissent**
- To **oppose**
- To **object**

If you want to express the *standard* or *quality* of something
that justifies a downvote:

- unsatisfactory
- inaccurate
- incorrect
- low quality
- wrong

Answer (score 1):

Consider the slang term, **[dis](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/dis)** (or *diss*)

> (slang, mainly US) to treat (someone) with contempt

Answer (score 0):

> The word *nay* as a noun is a [vote](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nay) against.

Answer (score -2):

**'veto'** is a good word for voting against something, even if this vote doesn't settle the issue like a political veto does.

Comment: Your experience might be different from mine, but my experience with the word *veto* is that it is far more powerful than just voting against it. It invokes a sense of finality or overruling, and operates at a higher level than "normal" votes.

Comment: Outside the political context, you can try and veto something, which shows that you feel strongly on it.  It depends on the situation what happens after that, though.  Even in the political context, vetos can be withdrawn or overridden.